# Can I set the height of the editor in textAngular for each editor individually?

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs

I've been using textAngular in a project and love the tool, but I need to be able to set the editor's height for each instance (e.g. I have the editor on one page where I'd like to set the height to 300px, but then on another page I'd like to have a small editor where I set the height to 100px).

I haven't been able to figure out how to do this and could use some guidance if anyone can point me in the right direction.

You can find the textAngular project here: https://github.com/fraywing/textAngular

I also posted a question in the project, but thought I might get a response faster here. The details of that post can be found here: https://github.com/fraywing/textAngular/issues/599

I have my HTML setup like so:

```
<text-angular placeholder="Write discovery insight here..."
    ta-html-editor-class="myform-content"
    ta-focussed-class="myfocused"
    ng-model="ndi.insight">
</text-angular>
```

And then I set up the CSS classes as follows:

```
.myform-content {
    height: 100px;
    max-height: 100px;
}

.myfocused {
    height: 100px;
    max-height: 100px;
}
```

However, this doesn't seem to get me what I was hoping. The height of the editor doesn't get set on initial load or change. Instead when I click inside the editor I get a big whitespace that appears between the input text box and the toolbar:

[image: view of what I get]

Can anyone point me in the right direction on how to do this?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

In your case you can just work with CSS classes on your text-angular object

```
<text-angular placeholder="Write discovery insight here..."
    ta-html-editor-class="myform-content"
    ta-focussed-class="myfocused"
    ng-model="ndi.insight"
    class="my-large-area">
</text-angular>

<text-angular placeholder="Write discovery insight here..."
    ta-html-editor-class="myform-content"
    ta-focussed-class="myfocused"
    ng-model="ndi.insight"
    class="my-small-area">
</text-angular>
```

So in this case you would have 2 implementations of the text-angular directive but both with their own class. In CSS you can adjust the height for each instance:

```
.my-large-area .ta-editor{
    height: 300px;
}
.my-small-area .ta-editor{
    height: 100px;
}
```

The height of the toolbar depends on the wrapping of the individual toolbars. When the container/screen gets smaller the toolbars will wrap and take up 2 lines of space, pushing the editor down.